# Geocoding API key should be server-restricted

Tags: google-maps, react-native

On the notes of this [page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key), there is a mention that the Geocoding API key should be server-restricted

> During development and testing, you can register a project for testing
>   purposes in the Google API Console and use a generic, unrestricted API
>   key. When you are ready to move your app or website into production,
>   register a separate project for production, create a **server-restricted
>   API key**, and add the key to your application.

Is the geocoding API only meant to be used on a server type instance?

Can I put the Geocoding API key on a mobile device by bundling it within the app using restriction for android/ios? I'm concerned that I will violate the said "server-restricted API key" clause.

PS. I'm aware that Google API keys can be restricted to android/ios/ip etc.

Comment: I'm not sure why I got downvoted, I also updated the question and added more details on the issue that there is a clause for " server-restricted API key"

Comment: So you'd prefer to use Google's Geolocation Web Service rather than the native API that comes with the mobile device?

Comment: @Iavor hi, what kind of native API are there? I’m would actually prefer to directly bundle my geolocation API key to the production app but I’m concerned that this is a violation of thr clause “server-restricted API key”. This way the mobile app would directly request “https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=%7B%7Bgmap_api_key%7D%7D&address=447f%20Masilang%20Pineda” using fetch/axios. Im using react  native btw

Comment: There is documentation on [Geolocation in React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html). Take a look at it and see if it has what you're looking for. That link you posted in your comment is calling the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) which is different to the [Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/intro). Which of the two services are you looking to use in your app?

Comment: @lavor thank you for pointing that out. What I want to use is geocoding, (finding the coordinates of addresses). Confusing part if that the geolocation and geocoding documentation almost looks the same on the 'get api key' part.

I have also further checked the official [google-maps-services-js](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js). It is not readily usable on a react-native application. I have to hack my way thru or use a server API so that we can 'restrict' the key for production

Comment: True, the Get API Key articles for those web services do look similar. Yeah, if you want to use a restricted key for web service requests through your mobile app, you'll have to set up a proxy server and make the desired web service requests from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to make Google Maps Web Service requests from a mobile device (without using the Google Maps SDK), you have to use an unrestricted key. Each mobile device has its own IP address and it is not feasible to set IP address restrictions to all the mobile devices that use your app.

Android or iOS API key application restrictions only work for requests made through the Android or iOS SDK.

If you want to use a restricted key for web service requests from mobile devices, you have to use a proxy server that makes the requests on behalf of the mobile app.

Comment: This is also my conclusion upon checking the list of API restriction rules and trying each one on react-native js side http request via fetch/axios

Comment: @lavor, have you tried the premium plan? As mentioned on this [page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key)  - premium plan have an additional type of restriction --- [use a client ID and digital signature](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key#client-id). I'm using standard for now but I plan to upgrade to a premium plan if necessary, whichever will cost less. Google maps premium plan or AWS lambda that is using the server-restricted API key

Comment: I have not tried the premium plan. Yeah, as a premium plan customer, you can authenticate your requests with either an API key or a client ID and digital signature.

Answer (score 0):

[image: use javascript maps sdk]

I’ve been reading the documentation and it seems that the Geocoding Web Service API is not fit for my use case. There is a “Javascript Google Maps API” that I can use.